# imaplib: what factors decide maintype is "text" or "multipart"

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I have been writing python code for small tool, wherein i am trying to fetch mails using  python libraries imaplib and email.
code statement is something like below.

```
import imaplib
import email
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.server')
mail.login('userid@mail.com', 'password')
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL")
latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
result, data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
raw_email = data[0][1]
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
maintype = email_message_instance.get_content_maintype()
```

I am executing the script from different host machines simultaneously.
Problem that I am facing is, while fetching the mail body, for **same incoming email**, on first host mac maintype is evaluated as "text" whereas for other host machine, its evaluated as "multipart" during script execution.

Would like to know how these values are determined at runtime and if I always want maintype to be "multipart", what standard layout should I follow while writing email in email body.

Comment: And what is the difference between `raw_email` on one machine and the other?

Comment: Hi zvone, 
raw_email for both cases has raw html code with multiple values. all most all html code is same except few differences. For maintype=multipart, Content-Type="multipart/alternative", boundary tag is present.
For maintype=text, Content-Type="text/html", boundary field is not present

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

> raw_email for both cases has raw html code with multiple values. all most all html code is same except few differences. For maintype=multipart, Content-Type="multipart/alternative", boundary tag is present. For maintype=text, Content-Type="text/html", boundary field is not present

Well, that answers the question. `get_content_maintype` returns first part of the `Content-Type`, which is `multipart` for **multipart**/alternative and `text` for **text**/html.

`multiplart/alternative` means there are multiple alternative versions of the email. Usually, that is html + text. Emails are often sent that way, because then they can be read by any client (the text part), but will still contain HTML formatting which will be used in clients which support it.

Apparently one of the emails was sent with both html and text, whereas the other contains only html.

Comment: thank you zvone for the comment. It helped me to get the detailed understanding. But please note multipart/alternative and text/html values are coming for the same email while parsing its body.

Comment: Then the server is giving different responses to different places.  Is this Exchange?

Comment: @nil13 I do't know why your emails are different. It depends on the configuration of the servers through which the email goes. How do you send the same email to windows and mac? Do you send it to two emails? If yes, what is the difference between the servers of one email and the other? Or do you send it to one email, but then read from two clients? If so, how? POP? IMAP? Anyway, the Python part of the mistery is resolved. It just tells you the truth. Now you have to see who or what is modifying the email.

Comment: @Max  yeah , its MS Exchange.

Comment: @zvone I have used IMAP, I've passed .PNG file thru mail along with my data, and somehow its giving consistent results when parsed thru multiple hosts.

Comment: @nil13 The details are missing. First, did you A) send one email to one recipient and then read it from two clients, or B) is there a forwarding rule which forwarded from one address to another, or C) did you send the email to two recipient addresses, or D) did you send two emails from the same client, or D2) was one of the emails a forward of the other, or E) did you send one email from one email client (e.g. Outlook) and another similar email from another client (e.g. Thunderbird)? Second question: what do you mean IMAP and MS Exchange? It should be either one or the other.

Comment: Hi zvone, i send an email to one mail box (kind of gmail ) and read that mail from different clients with imaplib. The problem that I was facing for that same mail, i got different values ( text on one client and multipart on other).

Comment: A) did you send one email to one recipient and then read it from two clients, - YES     B)is there a forwarding rule which forwarded from one address to another, - NO C)Did you send the email to two recipient addresses, - No D) did you send two emails from the same client, - YES D2) was one of the emails a forward of the other, - NO   E) did you send one email from one email client (e.g. Outlook) - YES (Only Outlook not thunderbird).

Comment: what do you mean IMAP and MS Exchange? It should be either one or the other -"I used imaplib of python to parse the email and my email Id is based on MS Exchange Server",
 As per your comment, I went thru RFC822 documentation, and found text + image format forms the content as  'multipart', and tried passing .PNG image in mail and it worked for me cause now from every client when i parse the mail, maintype=multipart.

Comment: @nil13 Just to confirm I got everything right: the email is received by MS Exchange and you are connecting to it via IMAP (your code from the question). You are running that code from two different machines, but they are connecting to the same IMAP server. You are downloading the same message, with the same UID, but you get different message contents? If that is so, it is really weird. I would blame it on Exchange...

Comment: @nil13 Wait a minute, you answered YES to both *"did you send one email" *and *"did you send two emails"* - which one is it?

Comment: @zvone yeah it is weird because exchange responds in different ways to same email id with same UID  , Just to reconfirm I sent only one email